How to include dependencies of local debian package in apt autoremove mechanism?
I created (via CMake but that is not important) a debian package which contains my application: my_app.deb which has a dependency on a 3rd party package in standard Debian repository (located in /etc/apt/sources.list)
dpkg-deb -I ./my_app.deb

...
Depends: some-lib
Description: my application
...

When I call sudo apt install ./my_app.deb it gets installed nicely along automatic installation (via the Internet) of some-lib. However, when i remove my application, some-lib is not included in autoremove mechanism:
sudo apt remove my-app (works)
sudo apt autoremove (doesn't work, some-lib remains installed)
Question: how to include dependencies of a local debian package to autoremove mechanism so they can be automatically removed afterwards?
Note: please feel free migrate this question elsewhere if it doesnt belong to SO, but I would like to get some help! Thanks!

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Unfortunately, the options when voting to close are limited; we could nominate this question for migration to [su] (or a small number of specialized sites) but not to [unix.se]. Furthermore, migrations are discouraged for users who are not familiar with the policies of the target site. It's probably simpler for everyone involved if you delete this yourself and figure out where to repost it.

Having said that, my expectation would be for autoremove to purge the package if it is now genuinely not depended on by anything. Probably name the actual library package and include information about its dependency and status information after removing your package; see also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Perhaps see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102467/why-does-apt-get-autoremove-uninstall-less-packages-than-aptitude-remove-does which actually explains this I think.

aptitude why might be your friend - perhaps something else depends on or recommends the same library?
